# Keep the document ID when copy document to another web app

Tags: document-id

I have 2 web apps on sharepoint SERVER 2013
I  want to copy documents from the fist app to the second app ( app for records) once documents are approved
and documents keep their documents ID

Can i set up this feature on sharepoint 2013

Comment: How can I preserve the Document ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot preserve the Document ID OOTB. You have 2 options:

Option 1:

Add Custom code to handle that, so basically, read the document ID from the source and create it on the destination.

The static name of the field is _dlc_DocId. You can get it from the list item:

```
string DocID = listitem.Properties["_dlc_DocId"].ToString();
```

http://blogs.devhorizon.com/reza/2010/09/26/querying-document-sets-using-spsitedataquery/

Option 2:

Use a 3rd party migration tool like Share-gate or Metalogix, etc that will do that for you.

Comment: for what are used these tools ?

Comment: can you give me useful links for the first option,please

Comment: Somebody knows a method to move a document on a other site with keeping the original document ID ?
I cannot understand why it generates a new ID

Comment: please take a look at this link https://www.plusconsulting.com/blog/2013/08/sharepoint-2013-2010-document-id-service-preserving-retaining-ids-move-cop-documents/

Comment: i use workflow to move document to another site collection in another web app,

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue before and used the Chris O'Brien SharePoint Content Migration Wizard and it was amazing. You don't have to code anything. Just enter the site collections URL and destination. https://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/

The below URL will help you learn how to use the application.
http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2007/12/introducing-sharepoint-content.html

I would try this solution in your development location first to learn how to use it.

Comment: that's not what i want , i need to copy content between site collection , not migration

Comment: Sorry. Your original question says move... You can still copy items though.

Comment: i edited the question